# how to separate the data depending on their cluster in R

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis

I am working with a data frame containing diferent time series. I have 157 days or time series and I have done clustering with it. To do so, I have used the *pam* command.

Therefore, now I know which day corresponds to each cluster. What I want is to separate my data frame depending on their clusters. So, create a data frame just with the time series from the first cluster. I add below some pictures of my source.

[That's the traindata just with two different days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHWyw.png)

[Clustering using pam command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx2g9.png)

It will be great if anybody can help me out.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: If you provide a small reproducible example, it would be much easier helping you.

Comment: When you provide your data and code as images, it means that we have to type it all in again. Please just put your code in the question so that we can cut-and-paste. For your data, please use `dput` to create a text version of the data that you paste into the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `split()`

```
data = data.frame(days=rep(1:30,3),cluster=sample(c(1:3),90,replace = T))
days = split(data,data$cluster)

days[1] #Days that were assigned to the first cluster
```